# Position elements inside word document generated using pure JS

Tags: javascript, ms-word, css-position

I am generating a word page from my page by using the blob object. However I am not able to figure out how to position the elements inside the word document. For eg, I want to align my table in the center of the page.

The following is the css part of it. Can someone suggest a crack for this?

Thanks!

```
 css = (
              '<style>' +
              '@page Word{size: 841.95pt 595.35pt;mso-page-orientation: landscape;  margin:1.0in 1.25in 1.0in 1.25in;}' +
              'div.Word {page: Word;}' +
              'table{border-collapse:collapse; }td{border:1px gray solid;width:10em;padding:2px;}th{border:1px gray solid;width:10em;padding:2px;}.tds{text-align:right}'+
              '</style>'
            );
```

Comment: "I want to align my table in the center of the table" do you mean "I want to align my table in the center of the page" or do you mean you have a table in a table?

Comment: Ah, I mean align it in the center of the page, my bad